# EBS storage for Amazon Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ebs

Im learning about AWS for a subject in the university.

About 20 days ago I started to learn about Elasticsearch because I need querys that DynamoDB can't do.

I'm trying to use only the Free Tier and I created some domains, put data  through Lambda (like 100 KiB) and then deleted it.

Then I checked the Billing and I realized that 4.9GB has been used for EBS storage. The Free Tier provide 10GB per month but the problem is that I don't know how I used all that storage and if there is a way to limit it because I dont want to exceed the usage limits.

I will be grateful for any kind of explanation or advice to not exceed the limit.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unaware with *preventive step* which can restrict your billing.

However, using Cloudwatch billing alarm, you'd be notified immediately as soon as it breaches billing threshold.

Please have look at [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html#turning_on_billing_metrics) for detailed AWS documentation on it.